# Как лучше выложить приложение asp.net с подключенной БД к нему?

Tags: asp.net, база-данных

Хочу выложить свое первое веб приложение для критики исходного кода и того, как оно работает. К приложению подключена БД. Как лучше выложить данное приложение в интернет вместе с БД?

Answer (score 2):

Поставьте его на домашнем компьютере и выложите [ваш IP](http://yandex.ru/yandsearch?text=%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B9+IP&lr=213) адрес в тред. Исходный код и SQL запрос для генерации базы выложите на [GitHub](https://github.com/) Также может потребоваться выключить firewall, перенастроить виртуальные хосты в веб интерфейсе роутера и купить статический IP у провайдера.